# Receive events with Angular in order

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, dom-events, angularjs-service

I have some trouble managing events in AngularJs.
In a service I dispatch events with the following line of code :

```
 $rootScope.$emit("FNH."+this.status, flowNodeHelper);
```

In a service "S1" I receive the event in the following way :

```
    $rootScope.$on('FNH.READY', function(event, flowNodeHelper) {
        flowNodeHelperService.setActive(flowNodeHelper);
    });
    $rootScope.$on('FNH.ACTIVE', function(event, flowNodeHelper) {
        flowNodeHelperService.setCompleting(flowNodeHelper);
    });
    $rootScope.$on('FNH.COMPLETING', function(event, flowNodeHelper) {
        flowNodeHelperService.setCompleted(flowNodeHelper);
    });
    $rootScope.$on('FNH.COMPLETED', function(event, flowNodeHelper) {
        flowNodeHelperService.setClose(flowNodeHelper);
    });
```

In a directive I receive event in the same way :

```
     $rootScope.$on('FNH.READY', function(event, flowNodeHelper) {
           console.log(flowNodeHelper + " status is ready");
      });
      $rootScope.$on('FNH.ACTIVE', function(event, flowNodeHelper) {
         console.log(flowNodeHelper + " status is  active");
      });
      $rootScope.$on('FNH.COMPLETING', function(event, flowNodeHelper) {
          console.log(flowNodeHelper + " status is completing");
      });
      ...
```

In my service "S1" when I receive event "FNH.READY", I call the `flowNodeHelper.setCompleting()` function which dispatch an event of type FNH.ACTIVE with `$rootScope.$emit`. 
Same thing to go from ACTIVE status to COMPLETING status, etc. workflow is going on.

In "S1" I receive events in the good order READY, then ACTIVE, then COMPLETING, ...
But in my directive I receive them in the other order : COMPLETED then COMPLETING, then ACTIVE, then READY !!

How can I do to receive events in the same time in my "S1" service and in my directive please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strange, it works if I do the following for each call to flowNodeHelperService in S1 :

```
$timeout(function() {
     flowNodeHelperService.setActive(flowNodeHelper);
}, 1);
```